# evaluate string expression in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, rlang, nse

I would like to pass the `label_format` expression to ggplot but I'm getting an error

```
#toy df
df <- data.frame(
  x = 1:10,
  y = seq(0.1,1,by=0.1),
  label_format = "scales::percent_format(accuracy=0.1)"
)

ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y))+
  geom_point()+
  scale_y_continuous(label=!! rlang::parse_expr( label_format))

Error in parse_exprs(x) : object 'label_format' not found
```

I would like to evaluate the string to end up with this plot with formatted y-axis:

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y))+
  geom_point()+
  scale_y_continuous(label=scales::percent_format(accuracy = 0.1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The scales don't have access to the global data to evaluate expressions stored in columns of the data. You can use unparsed expressions as follows though:

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(
  x = 1:10,
  y = seq(0.1,1,by=0.1)
)

label_format <- "scales::percent_format(accuracy=0.1)"

ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y))+
  geom_point()+
  scale_y_continuous(label= eval(parse(text = label_format)))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-01-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: nice!  `text = unique(df$label_format)` works with my original df